# Cross-Platform GUI development between wxPython and Mono

Tags: mono, webkit, cross-platform, wxpython

I've been thinking to give GUI development a try lately and am torn with the choice of between wxPython and Mono.

Judging from what I've seen out there, wxPython people seem to use the WebKit trick to produce nice (doesn't have to be beautiful) UI.

How hard is it to do the following in each of the platform:

1) Custom Control

2) Use HTML rendering

I don't quite understand how far the HTML rendering works via WebKit in wxPython (i.e.: does it support separate CSS/JS files? how's the JS support? do we need to write extra wxPython code to run the JS? how hard it is to integrate between JS events and wxPython widgets? what are the usual strategy of integrating WebKit with wxPython?)

Mind to share your thought on this subject? I specifically pick either wxPython or Mono, not Java Swing for no reason.

PS: I'm aware of certain limitation of cross-platform UI (as in: it won't be 100% native) and I could care less of such things.

Answer (score 2):

wxPython has wxWebkit available via the new WebView widget, but WebKit is only available on Mac and Linux right now. WebView uses a different rendering engine on Windows called Trident from IE (see http://wxpython.org/CHANGES.html). So you'll want to keep that in mind.

Either way, we're talking about browser engines that display HTML, CSS, etc. They should, theoretically, display whatever those engines support. You'll have to look up their specifications to be sure and also make sure to check if the port supports everything. As I understand it, they should definitely support the usual HTML and CSS and I would assume normal javascript. If I were you, I'd just create a simple window in wxPython and then load the web page you've created and see how it works.

I don't know how the javascript communicates with wxPython or if it even does. You'll want to ask on their mailing list for that kind of information.

Comment: Just an addendum, Pyside 1.1.0 has WebKit bindings that passes half the HTML5 tests ( excluding WebGL ).  As Mike points out, wxPython uses trident and by default it uses MSIE 7 which is unfortunate.

Comment: I think the wxWebkit project is supposed to add Windows support at some point, but I haven't seen an update in months